# Escape special characters in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a command that I want to put in a script but I'm having issues. The command is very picky and it looks like this:

```
command_to_run -H 'ip_address' -u 'user' -p 'passwd' --register naming_data "/location/of/backup/folder/" "[destination-location]"
```

I want to create an interactive bash script that asks the user for the ip_address, user, password, location of backup folder and a destination location. The problem I'm having is that I'm storing the user's input on variables (IP_ADD, USERNAME, etc) but when I pass it to the command like

```
$COMMAND -H '$IPADD' -u '$USERNAME' .....
```

but again my issues are in the single quotes, the "/" the "[]" ad passing the variables. Can anyone give me a hint and what I need to fix in order to have it working??

Comment: You need double quotes to have variables get expanded. Use single quotes for literal strings.

Comment: @EtanReisner Please phrase your answer in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like Etan said, use double quotes:

```
command_to_run -H "$ip_address" -u "$user" -p "$passwd" ....
```

Comment: The thing is that I have to pass the variables with single quotes, and other without and other with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes:

```
$COMMAND -H "$IPADD" -u "$USERNAME" ...
```

If you use single quotes in the shell, variables will not getting expanded meaning the literal `$USERNAME` will being used for the username.